# What's wrong with my selector value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, selector

I am currently developing a store for my client on Shopify. He wants me to add a functionality by which the user 's IP address is tracked and he gets to see the currency in of his own particular country. I am using the following code:
I want to change the selected value in dropdown to "AUD"
I only get some syntax error in this part:

```
jQuery("#select_selector option:selected").removeAttr("selected");

jQuery("#select_selector option:[value='"AUD"']").attr('selected', 'selected')
```

It says wrong syntax or arguement missing.

Comment: You have to escape your `"AUD"` like this `\"AUD\"`.

Comment: If AUD is text, then the quotes are not needed and can be `[value=AUD]`

Answer (score 2):

You need to concatenate your strings and variables. You can do this with the `+` operator. You also don't need the colon after `option`

```
jQuery("#select_selector option[selected]").removeAttr("selected");

jQuery("#select_selector option[value='" + AUD + "']").attr('selected', 'selected')
```

If `AUD` is not a variable, then you should just remove the quotes altogether.

```js
jQuery("#select_selector option[value=AUD]").attr('selected', 'selected')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select_selector">
      <option value="ABC">ABC</option>
      <option value="123">123</option>
      <option value="AUD">AUD</option>
      <option value="EFG">EFG</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried to run the same code, but I get the following error:--    n.fn.init [prevObject: n.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: "#select_selector option[value=AUD]"]

Comment: I also tried value=\"AUD\" but it didn't work for me

Comment: @AnchalVerma there must be something else that is wrong, because if you run the above code snippet it works without error.

Answer (score 0):

@Get Off My Lawn's code is working fine.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="select_selector">
      <option value="ABC">ABC</option>
      <option value="123">123</option>
      <option value="AUD">AUD</option>
      <option value="EFG">EFG</option>
</select>

<input type="button" value="click me" id="clickme">


<script>
 jQuery("#clickme").click(function(){
    jQuery("#select_selector option[selected]").removeAttr("selected");
    jQuery("#select_selector option[value=AUD]").attr('selected', 'selected');

});
</script>
```

or try this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3ytr61m2/1/)

And it will be good to have AUD/USD or any currency as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

`option:[value='"AUD"']` should be `option[value=AUD]`. No colon needed.

But actually you can just use

`jQuery("#select_selector").val('AUD');`

if you were using the samples from https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/currencies/show-multiple-currencies (which I recommend)
then that would be

`jQuery("#currencies").val('AUD');`

Not if you are auto selecting the currency for first time visitors you should also try storing the currency selection in local storage. Not only will that save you a geoip look-up it will also let customers override that value to the currency of their choice. Shopify's sample uses a cookie referred to as `cookieCurrency` in their code so your GeoIP lookup could first test that and only do the lookup if it is not set.